# reward for not doing an avairah

Tags: reward-punishment

According to Rabenu Yona (Sharei Teshuvah 3 9) that the reward for not doing an avairah is having done the mitzvah of Yiras Shomiam, why isn't every עשה דוחה לא תעשה, truly an עשה דוחה לא תעשה ועשה?
I know that the Seforim ask the question, but cannot remember which ones

Comment: Huh? I'm not following.

Comment: @SethJ He's saying that in every Lo Saasei there is a hidden Asei.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is a question. "Asei Doche Lo Saasei" says that if the Torah commands to do one thing and also not to do it, you must do it. Why would the Rabeinu Yona create a difficulty on that?

Comment: Did you mean "why *isn't* every..."?

Comment: @rabbi I have seen a similar discussion to this in Tanya, I think, where it is elucidated that the energy spent avoiding a transgression is somehow calculated as its own mitzvas aseh

Answer (score 3):

You don't automatically fulfill *yir'as HaShem* for every sin you are not doing. As is strongly and repeatedly implied in your cited passage from *Sha'arei T'shuva*, *yir'as HaShem* is an obligation on a person to avoid doing a sin when he would otherwise be tempted and have the opportunity to do it. As such, *yir'as HaShem* is not an עשה intrinsic to every לא תעשה.

Comment: but regarding having to transgress the lo saseh - as in every aseh docheh lo saseh - besides for the lo saseh being reason not to to the act, the mitzvh of yiras shomain should be another reason not to do it.